# Google chrome sandboxing web page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Users of one web app reported some strange behavior where they cannot use certain functionalities unless they open private browsing mode.

I have taken a look and this is the error message they get in the console.

**Ignored call to 'confirm()'. The document is sandboxed, and the 'allow-modals' keyword is not set.**

I have used onclick attribute on an anchor element

```
<a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure ...?');" ...
```

This is happening in the main document, it is not served in an iframe. It is not happening all the time but randomly appearing.

Any ideas as to why this happens? Everything I have found so far is mentioning iframe usage.

Comment: so, you've confirmed it happens to you, same web page randomly?

Comment: Yes it happens in the same web app, to multiple users but not all the time. It happens on a random occasion and if they close the browser and start it again it would work. Also in the private browsing mode it works all the time without this issue

Comment: has this happened to **you**? Users can be less than ideal when it comes to actual troubleshooting - you need to troubleshoot it personally rather than rely on the reports of *users*

Comment: Not to me on my computer but we did a screen-share session where I have taken a look at the console. These users are employees of the same company they are not some unfamiliar people.

Comment: fair enough - odd, and definitely not in a iframe somehow - probably some obscure chrome bug, try a different version of chrome - or stop using prompt/alert/confirm etc, it's 2021 :p